# Wordpress Warning: Cannot modify header information - wp-includes/rewrite.php :1

Tags: php, wordpress, warnings

I am getting warning on my wordpress site:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/8305169/html/wordpress/wp-includes/rewrite.php:1) in /home/content/8305169/html/wordpress/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1207
```

I am unable to access my admin panel. I tried removing extra space before starting php tag and after closing php tag but not worked for me.

EDIT:

I have two site having the same issue.

Error i am getting on my other site is:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/69/8305169/html/POWER/wp-includes/shortcodes.php:1) in /home/content/69/8305169/html/POWER/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1207
```

Please suggest me what should i do.

Thanks

Comment: it seems extra space is only issue here, please clear browser cache or check in another browser.

Comment: i think you are having session start two times check the pluggable.php. and also included files

Comment: @Irfan where to put ob_start().

Comment: @HelpingHands : I tried clearing browser cache and checked in other browser as well. Not working.

Comment: then put ob_start(); at first line in that file and check again.

Comment: What have you done that caused this error (your changes; added a plugin; changed the code etc.)?  Without code this question is unlikely to be solved. Try [searching for other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[wordpress]+%22Cannot+modify+header+information%22) (note the huge amount of duplicates, look out for useful hints, there won't be the 100% matching solution to your problem)

Comment: @try-catch-finally: I haven't installed any new plugin. the site was working fine few days ago. I even tried deactivating my theme via FTP and plugins as well. But still the issue not solved.

Comment: In your theme's header.php or index.php as suitable.

Comment: @HelpingHands: Are you talking about rewrite.php file?

Comment: @Irfan: I added ob_start(); but not working.

Comment: @HelpingHands: Not working :( .

Comment: Check this : http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_do_I_solve_the_Headers_already_sent_warning_problem.3F

Comment: @HelpingHands: I have performed these step before posting my issue here.. not work for me. :(

Comment: Please share code of you file rewrite.php by update question.

Comment: @HelpingHands: Can not share the code by update question as the body is limited to 30000 characters.. Any alrternate?

Comment: also use in bottom `ob_flush`

Comment: :( still the same issue.